# Map.forEachLayerAtPixel callback function has an empty rgba array

Tags: openlayers

Using a bit of code found on one of the examples (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html), I'm trying to get a change in the pointer representation whenever I'm hovering on a non-transparent part of a specific layer.

```js
map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    if (evt.dragging) {
        return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    var hit = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(pixel, function(layer, rgba) {
        return rgba[3] == 0;
    }, {
        'layerFilter': function(layer) {return layer == aisLayer;}
    });
    map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Unfortunately, the rgba variable in the callback function of Map.forEachLayerAtPixel is empty.
According to the documentation (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#forEachLayerAtPixel), this second arguments should be an array holding rgba value or null if the layer does not support it.

Well, for me, it's not null but it has no rgba value. It's just an empty Uint8array.

For information, here is the layer I'm working with, generated by a geoserver instance:

```js
var aisLayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new TileWMS({
        // url: 'http://192.168.8.157:8600/geoserver/gwc/service/wms',
        url: 'http://192.168.8.157:8600/geoserver/ais/wms',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'ais:shipinfosview',
            'VERSION': '2.0.0',
            'SRS': 'EPSG:900913',
            'CQL_FILTER': 'time>2020-05-17T18:10:00'
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        projection: 'EPSG:900913',
    })
});
```

Any idea what's wrong here ?

Thanks!

Comment: forEachLayerAtPixel cannot work if the canvas is tainted.  You must specify a crossOrigin option in the source (and the server must be et up to allow it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mike pointed out, crossOrigin must be specify to allow pixel manipulation.
That's actually mentionned in the doc.

However, changing just this for the layer that I was working with was not enough.

Because I was working with multiple layers, Openlayers seems to merge those layers into one.
One of those layer didn't have that `crossOrigin` parameters and I was still getting an empty array.

To avoid this and solve my issue, it is necessary that Openlayer does not merge all the layer into one canvas.
I made a wild guess and changed the `className` parameter of the `aisLayer` to something not default. And indeed, a new canvas was created that had not the default name.

I'll be glad to have some clarifications on the how and the why of this behaviour if you have any.

Below is a working solution:

```js
let aisLayer = new TileLayer({
    className: 'ais-layer',
    source: new TileWMS({
        // url: 'http://192.168.8.157:8600/geoserver/gwc/service/wms',
        url: 'http://192.168.8.157:8600/geoserver/ais/wms',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'ais:shipinfosview',
            'VERSION': '2.0.0',
            'SRS': 'EPSG:900913',
            'CQL_FILTER': 'time>2020-05-17T18:10:00'
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        projection: 'EPSG:900913',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    })
});

const source = new VectorSource({
    format: new GeoJSON(),
    url: './data/countries.json',
});
const layer = new VectorLayer({
    source: source,
});

const map = new Map({
    target: 'map-container',
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new XYZSource({
                url: 'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg'
            })
        }),
        layer,
        aisLayer,
    ],
    view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([0, 0]),
        zoom: 2
    })
});


map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    if (evt.dragging) {
        return;
    }
    let pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    let hit = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(pixel, function(layer, rgba) {
        return rgba[4] != 0;
    }, {
        'layerFilter': function(layer) {
            return layer.ol_uid == aisLayer.ol_uid;
        }
    });
    map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```